# Mount pendrive in chroot on Android

Tags: linux

I have a fedora chroot running on an Android device and want to be able to plug a USB pen drive into the Android device and have it accessible to a user in the fedora chroot.

The pen drive is mounted to /mnt/usbhost2 within Android.
I have created a folder within /media of the fedora chroot as a mount point this folder (/usb) is owned by the user that needs access to the usb device.

I have then tried the following command the mount the USB device to this folder:

```
$bbox mount -o bind /mnt/usbhost2 $mnt/media/usb
```

Which does work however the usb folder is no longer accessable by the user (only root user has access).
Before the mount the usb folder ls -l out put:

```
drwxrwxr-x username username 4096
```

However after the mount the ls -l out put it:

```
d---rwxr-x username media_rw 8192
```

So the question is how to I get the owner to have access again, simply using chmod does not work. I guess it has something to do with that fact that the usb device is formatted FAT32.

Is there another way I could mount this drive in the chroot that would give the user access?

Comment: This is a puzzle.  You say, “only root user has access,” but `d---rwxr-x` (075) should mean that everybody in the `media_rw` group (except for your special user) has full access (7), and that _everybody else_ (i.e., not the user or in the group) has read-only access (5).  Have you tried accessing the drive as some other user?  Other things to try: (1) `chown` the mount point to a user _other than_ username.  (2) Check the documentation for `mount` on your system.  If it supports any of `noowners`, `-u`, or `-uid`, use it.